# Geoprocessing operations re-introduce geometry errors after "repair geometry" succeeds

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, geometry

I am working with a shapefile that has many small, detailed polygons. After exporting it to a feature class in a geodatabase, I found that some operations (for example, Snap in the Editing Toolbox) seemed to be hanging. Based on previous experience, I thought that geometry errors were causing my processes to hang. I ran the "Repair Geometry" tool several times until "Check Geometry" no longer identified any errors. Every operation I have performed on the feature class since has re-introduced more geometry errors. Simply using the "Project" tool to project the feature class into a projected coordinate system caused "Check Geometry" to report a multitude of errors (mostly self-intersections) on features that were not identified as having errors on my initial attempt to clean this feature class.

Is there any hope that I can fix this shapefile? Running several "Repair Geometry" processes after every geoprocessing operation is an unattractive option due to the size of this dataset.

Additionally, could something besides these errors be causing my processes to hang?

Thanks.